# php script to excute bash script and display results on webpage.

Tags: php, linux, bash

I'm trying to create very simple page that will look up email address in a logfile

I wrote a bash script (with complex awk and sed queries ) that accepts single argument (email address) and it will display the output as follows.

```
DATE                    email                      phone 
31/1/2013               test@example.com           1800-000-000
```

how can I go about creating a webpage that will only take an email address and a search button that will simply execute the bash script in the backend and display the output to the screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 exec ("/path/to/script", $output);
```

That will output result into the $output variable.

You can then create page.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="address" />
<input type="submit" value="Post!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the index.php you can put such code:

```
<?php
     if ($_POST && $_POST['address']) {
          exec ("/path/to/script " . escapeshellarg($_POST['address']), $output); 
          echo $output;
     }
```

Comment: where do I put "exec ("/path/to/script", $output); " in my index.php or in my bash script?

Comment: You should use `escapeshellarg()` around the post variable.

Comment: Well, I'm getting blank screen, where should I put escapeshellarg(), my php skills are really basic :(

Comment: @user1007727 Please, at first, please create page with such code "<?php    echo 'test';  ?>" With such basic code you could ensured that webserver and php works fine, then if 'test' will be echoed I will provide you more help.

Comment: got blank screen with "test" seems like php is working fine :) any other next step / suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Then please try just replace "echo 'test';" by "exec ("/path/to/script someaddress", $output); echo $output;" Then we will be sured that exec works correctly. There could be some restrictions related to using exec function.